# Direct limit of $\mathscr{F}(U)$ is the same as direct limit of $\mathscr{F}(X_f)$, where $P\in U$ and $f\notin P$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

This question is from Mumford's *The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes* (Section I.4).

Let $X\subseteq k^n$ be an irreducible algebraic set,
$R$ its affine coordinate ring.
Since $X$ is irreducible,
$I(X)$ is prime and $R$ is an integral domain.
Let $K$ be its field of fractions.

Let $\underline{o}_x=\{f/g\mid f, g\in R, g(x)\neq 0\}\subseteq K$.
Now for $U$ open in $X$,
let $$\underline{o}_X(U)=\bigcap_{x\in U}\underline{o}_x.$$

Let $X_f=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$.

**The author said:** 
Since the sets $X_f$ are a basis of the Zaiski topology of $X$,
we have
$$\varinjlim_{x\in U}\underline{o}_X(U)=\varinjlim_{x\in X_f}\underline{o}_X(X_f).$$

**My Question:**
Why?
I think the first part I have to prove is that
$$\bigcup_{x\in U}\underline{o}_X(U)=\bigcup_{x\in X_f}\underline{o}_X(X_f).$$
But I cannot prove it.

Comment: If you know some complex analyis compare $\mathcal O_x$ with germs of meromorphic functions at a point. Might be insightful.

Comment: @Ghosh Thx. But I am looking for a purely algebraic proof. I will come back to see your hint after learning complex analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The sets $X_f$ are cofinal in the poset of open sets of $X$ containing $x$ (this follows from the $X_f$ being a basis for the topology of $X$). Since stalks are calculated as colimits, it suffices to calculate along any cofinal collection - which is exactly the claim the author makes.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you answer. Which book where I can find the theorem you mentioned? "Since stalks are calculated as colimits, it suffices to calculate along any cofinal collection"

Comment: I don't have a reference offhand - just look at the definition of cofinal: a subcollection $A$ of a poset $B$ is cofinal iff for any $b\in B$ there is an $a\in A$ so that $b\leq a$. In particular, this means that the morphisms from any $b\in B$ to the colimit factor through the cofinal collection, so the colimit of the original collection and the cofinal collection satisfy the same universal property and must be isomorphic.